# Flutter search listview in array index problem

Tags: json, flutter, api, dart, search

This is my address button code. I want to search for an address in an array of addresses with multiple addresses. But I can't find it. It stuck with index problem in this part. How to call index loop? I've tried every way.
I am now able to display all addresses in a listview. And I want to search for an address by typing at least a letter to show the address first.

```
 onSearchAddr(String text) {
if (text.isNotEmpty) {
  setState(() {
    for (var item in searchitems) {
      // final addr = item.address!
      //     .where((element) => element.addr1!.contains(text))
      //     .toList();
      // final itemList = searchitems
      //     .where((e) => e.address![0].addr1 == addr[0].addr1)
      //     .toList();
      // print('addr: $addr');
      // print('itemList: $itemList');
      if (item.address![0].addr1.toString().contains(text)) {
        searchitems.clear();
        searchitems.add(item);
        print('searchitems if: ${searchitems.length}');
        print('searchitems if: ${searchitems[0].address!.length}');
      } else {
        print('Not Contain:');
      }
    }
  });
} else {
  setState(() {
    searchitems.clear();
    searchitems =
        items.where((element) => element.custnum == searchText).toList();
    print('searchitems else: ${searchitems.length}');
  });
}
```

}

This is json

```
 {
    "items": [
  {
   "custnum": "",
   "name": "",
    "address": [
    {
        "shipto": 0,
        "addr1": "",
        "thanon": "",
        "tambon": "",
        "amphur": "",
        "prov_code": "",
        "province": "",
        "zipcode": "",
        "country": "",
        "contact": "",
        "postcode": ""
    },
    {
       "shipto": 1,
        "addr1": "",
        "thanon": "",
        "tambon": "",
        "amphur": "",
        "prov_code": "",
        "province": "",
        "zipcode": "",
        "country": "",
        "contact": "",
        "postcode": ""
    },
    {
        "shipto": 2,
        "addr1": "",
        "thanon": "",
        "tambon": "",
        "amphur": "",
        "prov_code": "",
        "province": "",
        "zipcode": "",
        "country": "",
        "contact": "",
        "postcode": ""
    },
    {
        "shipto": 3,
        "addr1": "",
        "thanon": "",
        "tambon": "",
        "amphur": "",
        "prov_code": "",
        "province": "",
        "zipcode": "",
        "country": "",
        "contact": "",
        "postcode": ""
    }
     {
    "custnum": "",
    "name": "",
    "address": [
       {
        "shipto": 0,
        "addr1": "",
        "thanon": "",
        "tambon": "",
        "amphur": "",
        "prov_code": "",
        "province": "",
        "zipcode": "",
        "country": "",
        "contact": "",
        "postcode": ""
    },
    {
       "shipto": 1,
        "addr1": "",
        "thanon": "",
        "tambon": "",
        "amphur": "",
        "prov_code": "",
        "province": "",
        "zipcode": "",
        "country": "",
        "contact": "",
        "postcode": ""
    },
]
```

}
],

Comment: could you also include your class model too?

Answer (score 0):

You can't clear a list when you are inside its loop, so change `onSearchAddr` to this:

```
onSearchAddr(String text) {
    if (text.isNotEmpty) {
      setState(() {
        searchitems.clear();
        for (var item in items) {
          for (var address in item.address) {
            if (address.addr1.toString().contains(text)) {
              searchitems.add(item);
            } else {
              print('Not Contain:');
            }
          }
        }
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        searchitems.clear();
        searchitems =
            items.where((element) => element.custnum == searchText).toList();
        print('searchitems else: ${searchitems.length}');
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: @Ppnncs was it what you want?